# consulta a base de datos me duplica los mismos al hacer join a otras tablas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy realizando una consulta a varias tablas, la tabla principal `t_persona` tiene 441,153 registros y la tabla `t_evaluación` tiene 471,558. La tabla evaluación puede tener varias veces el código de la persona ya que una persona puede tener 1 o mas evaluaciones.

Lo que necesito es que al hacer el `join` con la tabla `t_evaluación` me traiga la misma cantidad de registros que existen en `t_personas` (441,153); pero al hacerlo me trae más registros (471,558) que el total de la tabla evaluación. Y así con las demás tablas.

La estructura de la table `t_persona` es:

```
  codigo_persona character varying(12) NOT NULL,  
  id character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('vulnerabilidad.t_persona_id_seq'::regclass),
  nombres_apellidos character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  cedula character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  fecha_nacimiento date NOT NULL,
  edad integer NOT NULL,
  genero integer NOT NULL,
  meses integer,
  dias integer,
  CONSTRAINT codigo_persona PRIMARY KEY (codigo_persona),
  CONSTRAINT edadmaxima CHECK (edad <= 120),
  CONSTRAINT edadminima CHECK (edad >= 0),
  CONSTRAINT validargenero CHECK (genero >= 1 AND genero <= 2)
```

tabla `evaluacion`:

```
codigo_evaluacion character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  codigo_persona character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  codigo_descripcion_situacion integer NOT NULL,
  cbi integer NOT NULL,
  peso double precision NOT NULL,
  talla double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
  embarazo character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  fecha_abordaje date NOT NULL,
  codigo_origen character varying(12),
  codigo_condicion_especial character varying(12),
  CONSTRAINT codigo_evaluacion PRIMARY KEY (codigo_evaluacion),
  CONSTRAINT t_estado_nutricional_t_evaluacion_fk FOREIGN KEY (codigo_descripcion_situacion)
      REFERENCES vulnerabilidad.t_estado_nutricional (codigo_descripcion_situacion) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT t_evaluacion_codigo_condicion_especial_fkey FOREIGN KEY (codigo_condicion_especial)
      REFERENCES vulnerabilidad.t_condicion_especial (codigo_condicion_especial) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT t_persona_t_evaluacion_fk FOREIGN KEY (codigo_persona)
      REFERENCES vulnerabilidad.t_persona (codigo_persona) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT "validarCbi" CHECK (cbi > 49 OR cbi < 387),
  CONSTRAINT "validarDescripcionSituacion" CHECK (codigo_descripcion_situacion > 0 OR codigo_descripcion_situacion < 4),
  CONSTRAINT validarcbi CHECK (cbi >= 50 AND cbi <= 386),
  CONSTRAINT validarpeso CHECK (peso >= 1.00::double precision AND peso <= 150.00::double precision)
```

tabla `t_ubicacion_persona`

```
codigo_ubicacion_persona character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  codigo_estado character varying(2) NOT NULL,
  codigo_municipio character varying(2) NOT NULL,
  codigo_parroquia character varying(2) NOT NULL,
  codigo_sector character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  codigo_persona character varying(12),
  id serial NOT NULL,
  numero_ubicacion integer,
  cedula_ubicacion character varying,
  poblacion_indigena character varying(200),
  CONSTRAINT t_ubicacion_persona_pk PRIMARY KEY (codigo_ubicacion_persona),
  CONSTRAINT "foranes t_persona" FOREIGN KEY (codigo_persona)
      REFERENCES vulnerabilidad.t_persona (codigo_persona) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

tabla `t_registro_persona`

```
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  codigo_registro character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  codigo_persona character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  codigo_evaluacion character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT t_registro_persona_pkey PRIMARY KEY (codigo_registro, codigo_persona, codigo_evaluacion)
)
```

y la tabla `t_registro`:

```
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  codigo_registro character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  fecha_registro timestamp without time zone,
  codigo_usuario character varying(12),
  codigo_transcriptor character varying(12),
  CONSTRAINT codigo_registro PRIMARY KEY (codigo_registro)
)
```

Necesito hacer `join` a todas estas tablas; porque es necesario para el reporte tener datos de la evaluación, de la ubicación, los datos de la persona y la fecha del registro, que se almacena en la tabla `t_registro`. Pero para poder saber la fecha de registro de cada persona se hace a través de la tabla `t_registro_persona`.

utilizo el siguiente query para la consulta

```
select * from vulnerabilidad.t_persona as p
join vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion as ev on p.codigo_persona = ev.codigo_persona
join vulnerabilidad.t_ubicacion_persona as up on up.codigo_persona = p.codigo_persona
join vulnerabilidad.t_registro_persona as rp on rp.codigo_persona = p.codigo_persona
join vulnerabilidad.t_registro as r on r.codigo_registro = rp.codigo_registro
```

Esta me trae como resultado 547,201 registros. Lo que necesito es toda la información de las tablas pero solo con la cantidad de registros que hay en la tabla personas (441,153).

Comment: En primer lugar, la estructura de las tablas no dice mucho, deberías agregar la consulta. En segundo lugar ¿Qué esperas como resultado? Una persona tiene por ejemplo dos evaluaciones, pero quieres una sola fila por lo que la pregunta es ¿cuál de las dos evaluaciones te interesa mostrar?

Comment: En tu pregunta dices que la consulta te trae más registros, pero siempre muestras números con menos registros (medio millón) de los que tiene la tabla de personas (que tiene cuatro millones). Edité tu pregunta y le puse separadores de miles a los números, para que esto se haga evidente. Sugiero editar tu pregunta y corregir los datos, o bien el planteamiento que haces.

Comment: @Angel, ya con la edición se entiende bien el tema de los números, pero sigues sin explicar que resultado esperas si una persona tiene dos evaluaciones. Esto puedes explicarlo mejor, quizás, con un ejemplo de los datos, más que con palabras.

Un saludo.

Comment: Estoy realizando un count tomando como tabla principal la tabla t_persona con el total antes mencionado pero al hacer el join a la tabla t_evaluacion me trae el total de los registros de esta tabla y no los de la tabla persona, lo que necesito es tener el conteo de la tabla t_persona con su primera evaluacion, si tiene mas no son necesarias, solo necesito el conteo de las personas con su primera evaluacion

Answer (score -1):

Lo puedes resolver usando SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement
Algo así (obviamente agregando los join y todo lo necesario para tu caso):

```
SELECT DISTINCT codigo_persona  FROM t_registro.
```

Para mas info sobre "DISTINCT" [click aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Espero que te ayude. Saludos!

Comment: pero le puedo agregar varios distinct en la misma consulta?

Comment: Lo que hace es que sea distinta la combinación de todos los campos que has escrito detrás del **DISTINCT**. Puedes revisar la documentación del link que te deje. Ahí te explica como usarlo con mas detalle. Salutos!